# Using a theme for preferences screen

Tags: android, themes, preferences

I want the change the look of the preferences screen for an app I am working on.  On some phones the preferences are very translucent and it is quite difficult to read the preferences scheme, so I am going to change the visuals for it.

My question is how can I apply a theme to the preferences scheme?  Or failing that, how can I change the text color that show up for the various preferences.

In my current version, my preferences layout xml file starts with:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffa0a0a0">
```

This background color gives me an acceptable gray, but I would prefer to use a theme.

I tried putting a applying a couple of different themes in the preferences xml and the preferences layout xml and none of this has shown any effect.  I also tried setting andoid:textColor for the individual preferences items and in layout and that had no effect.

So how does one modify the visuals for the preferences scheme (preferably by using a theme)?

thanks in advance,

Jay

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The basic things are:

1. A theme for your preferences activity which defines styles for the preference widgets and other things. Take a look at the first theme in [themes.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml) - this defines the window background, text styles and the preference styles (`preferenceScreenStyle`, `preferenceCategoryStyle` etc)
2. Some styles for each of the preference widgets (which are referenced in `themes.xml`). For instance in [styles.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml) they define the `Preference.Category` and `Preference.PreferenceScreen` styles.
3. Apply the theme to your Activity. In your manifest change your opening activity tag for your preferences activity to `<activity android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"...`

If you want to inherit the default Android styles and then just override some of them, then add `parent="@android:style/Theme"` to the opening `<style...` tag of your theme.

Take a look at [Applying Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) for more info.

Comment: themes.xml: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml

Comment: styles.xml: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml

Comment: Better official links from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html): [themes.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml) - [styles.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml)