# changing the preference category label color background

Tags: android, android-preferences

I would like to change the color of the preference category bakcgorund. In my xml with preferences I have categories typed in this way:

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Synchronization"> ... </PreferenceCategory>
```

I am trying to change the background using xml attribute:

```
android:widgetLayout="@style/PreferenceCategory"
```

And the code in my styles.xml looks like:

```
<resources>
<style name="PreferenceCategory">
    <item name="android:background">@color/my_blue</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

But it isn't work properly. I have fatal exception:

```
08-13 01:43:09.111: WARN/dalvikvm(1329): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f090006
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:892)
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1869)
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:731)
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:318)
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.preference.Preference.onCreateView(Preference.java:416)
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.preference.Preference.getView(Preference.java:389)
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.preference.PreferenceGroupAdapter.getView(PreferenceGroupAdapter.java:221)
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1418)
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:670)
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:727)
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1598)
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1248)
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:912)
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1140)
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-13 01:43:09.141: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1329):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have the same fatal exception when I change the color form `@color/my_blue` to some hex code.

I know that I can use in AndroidManifest for my preference activity this xml attribute:

```
android:theme="@style/PreferencesTheme"
```

But it changes the background color of all my preference activity. In which way can I change the attributes of preferences parts?

Comment: can you post the full error log from the logcat for this?

Comment: I have edited my question and posted the full error log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are trying to pass a style/theme that only has a background color specified in it when it is expecting a style/theme/layout that contains a view to replace the current view in the preference with.

The example in the documentation for android:widgetLayout says

> a checkbox preference would specify a custom layout (consisting of
>   just the CheckBox) here

Another option would be to try and do this in code by overriding the onBindView() of the PreferenceCategory.

and yes, changing the theme in the AndroidManfiest.xml should change the background color (in this case) for the entire Application or Activity depending on where you specified it.

Comment: Yes, I have to write a simple layout. Using resources and items causes problems. I have posted working solution to my problem in answer.

Answer (score 7):

To me, this works:

For example ListSeparator item:

In styles.xml

```
<style name="ListSeparator">
<item name="android:background">@drawable/status_bar</item>
<item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">25dip</item>
<item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
<item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
<item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
<item name="android:paddingLeft">5sp</item>
</style>

<color name="custom_theme_color">#e6e6e6</color>

<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
<item name="android:colorBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
<item name="android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle">@style/ListSeparator</item>
</style>
```

Then, in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
android:name="MyActivityPreference"
android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" >
</activity>
```

Or view this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5564943/471690

Answer (score 3):

This is solution for my problem. In my file for example preference_category.xml I have to have a simple layout for the PreferenceCategory and than use it in `android:layout`. However `android:widgetLayout` doesn't work.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/my_blue"
>
<TextView 
android:id="@+android:id/title"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:textColor="@color/my_white"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textSize="16sp"
android:padding="5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
/>     
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I went down the same path and found that some resources are hidden and can't be styled.  The method of supplying a layout works whereas the widgetLayout would be referring to a view within the list item such as a checkbox or some other widget.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that worked for me is just to copy the preference_category.xml into res/layout folder and change the values right from there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- Layout used for PreferenceCategory in a PreferenceActivity. -->
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:id="@android:id/title"
        />
```

Just give the what ever color you want at the             `android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"` block